# Forcing non null values in DataGridView cells while editing

Tags: c#, datagridview

Hello I am writing a application that required the user to input the first name, last name and telephone #. These values can not be null.

What I am trying to accomplish is to validate the data and If the value is null to select the cell that is in question and force them to edit it or they will get the same error over and over again.

The data gets properly checked, however the cell doesn't get re selected and begin editing.  It just selects whatever cell I clicked on after the validation.  Here is my code.

```
private void datagridCustomers_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    curCell = datagridCustomers.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        if (e.FormattedValue.ToString() == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
            datagridCustomers.CurrentCell = curCell;
            curCell.Selected = true;
            datagridCustomers.BeginEdit(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting `Cancel` property of event should do the trick: it will not allow to leave the cell

```
private void datagridCustomers_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.FormattedValue.ToString() == string.Empty)    
        e.Cancel = true;    
}
```